# Main method not exiting in Jetty Websocket connection

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, jetty

When I'm establishing the Websocket connection, connection establishing but after closing the connection or any error occurred in connection, main thread not killing, i can see still JVM running mode only. After websocket server sending events, this connection not receiving any notification. **Once websocket connection disconnected with the server neither reconnecting nor exiting**.

**WebsocketClientEndpoint.java**

```
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketClientEndpoint.class);

    public void establishConnection(MessageHandler soket, String url, String token) {
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
    try {
      client.start();
      client.setMaxIdleTimeout(0);
      URI wsURI = new URI(url);
      ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
      if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(token)) {
        request.setHeader("Authorization", token);
      }
      client.connect(soket, wsURI, request);
      LOGGER.info("Connecting to :" + wsURI);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    LOGGER.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }

}
```

**MessageHandler.java**

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketError;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@WebSocket
public class MessageHandler {

  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandler.class);
  private Session session;

  public void handleMessage(String message) {
    LOGGER.info("Message>>>>>>>>>>>" + message);
  }

  @OnWebSocketClose
  public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
    this.session.close();
    LOGGER.info("connection closing");
    LOGGER.info("" + statusCode);
    LOGGER.info(reason);
  }

  @OnWebSocketConnect
  public void onConnect(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
    LOGGER.info("Connection Established");
  }

  @OnWebSocketError
  public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
    LOGGER.error("error:" + throwable.getMessage());

    if(session != null)
      session.close();
  }

  @OnWebSocketMessage
  public void onMessage(String msg) {
    LOGGER.info("Message Received : " + msg);
  }

}
```

**TestApp.java**

```
public class TestApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
     System.out.println("\n\n==================================== Start ==============================================\n\n");
     MessageHandler soket = new MessageHandler();
     WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint();
     clientEndPoint.establishConnection(soket, "ws://localhost:5566/java-websocket/sample", null);
     System.out.println("\n\n==================================== End ==============================================\n\n");
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
   }
  }
}
```

**Output is**:(Adding image not advisable but giving actual issue)
In below image can see still Main thread is not exit even though connection not established. how to terminate? I tried `System.exit(0)` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)` in `onClose()`&`onError()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think of `WebSocketClient` as a browser.

You start it, and then make many requests, different tabs, etc.

When you are done, you close the browser.

If you don't close the browser, the browser is still using resources on your machine.

When you `WebSocketClient.start()` a whole host of resources are allocated, but in your example code, you never `stop()`.

What I recommend you do, is in your `main()` method should manage the lifecycle of the `WebSocketClient` properly.

Have it create the `WebSocketClient`, configure it, and then `start()` it.

Then make/establish as many websocket connections as you want.

When you are done, you have to use `WebSocketClient.stop()` to end the `WebSocketClient` lifecycle (and cleanup allocated threads, the thread pool, executor, connection pools, ssl engines / ssl contexts, buffer pools, etc)